Vertex AI Vector Search Query via Golang Troubleshooting
I am attempting to utilize the Go Vertex AI SDK in order to use some of the functionalities on Vertex AI. Specifically, I want to query from a deployed matching engine index via Go. I am running this on go 1.22.5, and using cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform version 1.68.0
Here is my implementation:
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "context"

    "regexp"

    aiplatformpb "cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/apiv1/aiplatformpb"

    aiplatform "cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/apiv1"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"
)

func embedTexts() {
    ...
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    query_string_arr := []string{"Some text to be used as a query for nearest neighbors"}
    var project_id = "<project id>"
    var location = "us-central1"

    // Get text embeddings for query
    embeddings, err := embedTexts(project_id, location, query_string_arr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("The length of the embedding vector is:")
        fmt.Println(len(embeddings[0]))
    }

    // ensure that we are hitting the correct API endpoint for vector search client
    apiEndpoint := fmt.Sprintf("%s-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443", location)

    // initialize matching engine client
    c, err := aiplatform.NewMatchClient(ctx, option.WithEndpoint(apiEndpoint))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Vector Search Client successfully initialized!")
    }

    // // initialize structs to create request body

    //// 1. initialize the index datapoint restriction struct
    restricts_params := &aiplatformpb.IndexDatapoint_Restriction{
        Namespace: "<some namespace>",
        AllowList: []string{"<some value to allow for namespace>"},
    }

    //// 2. initialize the index datapoint struct
    query_datapoint := &aiplatformpb.IndexDatapoint{
        DatapointId:   "<Placeholder>",
        FeatureVector: embeddings[0],
        Restricts:     []*aiplatformpb.IndexDatapoint_Restriction{restricts_params},
    }

    //// 3. initialize the query struct
    find_nbrs_query := &aiplatformpb.FindNeighborsRequest_Query{
        Datapoint:     query_datapoint,
        NeighborCount: 50,
    }

    //// 4. initialize the nearest neighbors request struct
    req := &aiplatformpb.FindNeighborsRequest{
        IndexEndpoint:       "projects/<project number>/locations/us-central1/indexEndpoints/<vector search index endpoint id>",
        DeployedIndexId:     "<vector search deployed index id>",
        Queries:             []*aiplatformpb.FindNeighborsRequest_Query{find_nbrs_query},
        ReturnFullDatapoint: true,
    }

    // send request to vector search
    resp, err := c.FindNeighbors(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failing at vector search request time.")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Vector Search Request successfully sent!")
    }

    defer c.Close()

    for _, neighbor := range resp.GetNearestNeighbors() {
        fmt.Printf("Neighbor ID:%s\n", neighbor.Id)
    }
}


However, I've come across a particular error that I cannot seem to resolve.
rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled.

This is failing at the snippet of code where I am calling c.FindNeighbors. This seems to indicate that:

The endpoint I am using, us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443, is not the correct endpoint to be using for calling the vector search index endpoint.
The method I am using is incorrect somehow (although the compiler did not throw any errors at me).

In either of these cases, what methods should I be using? Or what endpoint should I be hitting? This is a rather open-ended question, but I am not sure how to proceed (I am also rather new to Go so please give some pointers as well if I seem to misunderstand something in my code snippet!)
Side note: I have also checked that I have full access to my GCP environment. In fact, my POST requests from CLI work as intended. I am just struggling with making the gRPC call via Go.
Another note: I have the correct index endpoint Id and the deployed index id. The deployed index id and index endpoint id is of the form:
DEPLOYED_INDEX_ID = "<name of vector search index>_<index id>"

INDEX_ENDPOINT_ID = "projects/<project number>/locations/us-central1/indexEndpoints/<vector search index endpoint id>"

I have verified, via writing the Python analogue of this code, that these exact parameters are sufficient to query from the vector search index I am using.
Update:
I have figured out that us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com:443 is not the correct endpoint. My vector search index is within a VPC network, therefore, the private service access requires a different endpoint.
Here is the new implementation.
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "context"

    "regexp"

    aiplatformpb "cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/apiv1/aiplatformpb"

    aiplatform "cloud.google.com/go/aiplatform/apiv1"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
    insecure "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"
)

// method to invoke text embeddings
func embedTexts(
    project, location string, texts []string) ([][]float32, error) {
...
}

// NOTE:
// In order to perform candidate generation, we must do the following:
// 0. Build struct to form request body of text embedding model
// 1. Call text embedding model to convert a string to a dense feature vector
// 2. Build the structs to form the request for the nearest neighbors search
// 3. Call vector search index

//////// 1. Make API request to text embedding model
// in main method

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    query_string_arr := []string{"<query contents>"}
    var project_id = "<project id>"
    var location = "us-central1"

    //////// 2. Call Text Embeddings

    // Get text embeddings for query
    embeddings, err := embedTexts(project_id, location, query_string_arr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("The length of the embedding vector is:")
        fmt.Println(len(embeddings[0]))
    }

    // ensure that we are hitting the correct API endpoint for vector search index
    // NOTE: Since we are hitting a PSA index (Private Service Access), we must route our request to the internal
    // gRPC endpoint

    grpc_conn, err := grpc.NewClient("10.25.0.5:10000", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Successfully connected to gRPC endpoint.")
    }

    // initialize matching engine client
    c, err := aiplatform.NewMatchClient(ctx, option.WithGRPCConn(grpc_conn))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Vector Search Client successfully initialized!")
    }

    defer c.Close()

    //////// 3. Create Request Body for Vector Search

    // // initialize structs to create request body

    //// 1. initialize the index datapoint restriction struct
    restricts_params := &aiplatformpb.IndexDatapoint_Restriction{
        Namespace: "<namespace>",
        AllowList: []string{<allowed namespace values>},
        DenyList:  []string{<denied namespace values>},
    }

    //// 2. initialize the index datapoint struct
    query_datapoint := &aiplatformpb.IndexDatapoint{
        DatapointId:   "Placeholder",
        FeatureVector: embeddings[0],
        Restricts:     []*aiplatformpb.IndexDatapoint_Restriction{restricts_params},
    }

    //// 3. initialize the query struct
    find_nbrs_query := &aiplatformpb.FindNeighborsRequest_Query{
        Datapoint:     query_datapoint,
        NeighborCount: 10,
    }

    //// 4. initialize the nearest neighbors request struct
    req := &aiplatformpb.FindNeighborsRequest{
        IndexEndpoint:       "projects/<project number>/locations/us-central1/indexEndpoints/<index endpoint id>",
        DeployedIndexId:     "<deployed_index_endpoint_name>_<index id>",
        Queries:             []*aiplatformpb.FindNeighborsRequest_Query{find_nbrs_query},
        ReturnFullDatapoint: false,
    }

    // send request to vector search
    resp, err := c.FindNeighbors(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failing at vector search request time.")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        fmt.Printf("Response object: %s", resp)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Vector Search Request successfully sent!")
    }

    for _, neighbor := range resp.GetNearestNeighbors() {
        fmt.Printf("Neighbor ID:%s\n", neighbor.Id)
    }

}


I realize that I have to somehow route the request to the gRPC host when initializing the matching engine client.
With that said, I am now getting a (different) error:
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 10.25.0.5:10000: connect: connection refused"

I am not sure why the connection is being refused here?

I also have an ongoing thread on google cloud forums for this exact issue: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Vertex-AI-Vector-Search-Unable-to-query-from-index-endpoint/m-p/791525#M8831
